# Android - set pin for Bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have been reading the [Bluetooth documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html) on Android's developer site.

I want to pair a Bluetooth device and then connect to it, but I don't want the request dialog to pop up (or even if it does set the pin using some API to dismiss it). I want to do it in Android 4.3+.

So far I see this involving the following steps:

1) App discovers device : use `BroadcastReceiver` to get [BluetoothDevice](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html)

2) App pairs the device : uses `BluetoothDevice.createBond()`, and registers a `BroadcastReceiver` to get confirmation of pairing completion

3) App connects to device : uses `BluetoothDevice.createRfCommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID)`

My understanding is that the pop dialog for pairing will be shown to the user after step 2.
I know there is a `setPin()` API (now public) in the `BluetoothDevice` class.

If I call it right after step 2, will the dialog still appear and wait for user input, or will it appear and then dismiss, resulting in pairing success ?

Also does step 3 involve any input from the user ?

Answer (score 0):

Step 3 doesn't involve user input.

I've been trying to do exactly the same, I use `setPin()` and it works, but the user Input dialogue is still there, there is an option to use `cancelPairingUserInput` but i'm not sure if this is still valid for API19 (that is the one which uses `setPin()` as far as I know...) or if there is another way to do it.

Hope this helps...